# How to pass parameter in the url in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been created student details in studententry.aspx page with using c# and asp.net.

When i insert student details, it has been displayed in the gridview.

And now in the gridview, i have been added one column name called result.

When i click result button, it links to studentresult.aspx page.

So when i click particular row result(studententry.aspx), it should pass parameter id in studentresult.aspx. I mean need to pass parameter in the url.

Here is my cs:

```
protected void btnresult_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("studentresult.aspx");
        }
```

I'm new to .net. I just links to "studentresult.aspx" page. and that page will be blank, I don't what i have to add.

Can anyone help me to pass parameter in the url?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Edit:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
        EnablePersistedSelection="True" BackColor="White" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Class" HeaderText="Class" SortExpression="Class" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section" 
                SortExpression="Section" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
                SortExpression="Address" />
                <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image" HeaderText="Image" ControlStyle-Width="50" ControlStyle-Height = "50">                
                <ControlStyle Height="50px" Width="50px"></ControlStyle>
                </asp:ImageField> 
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
               <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnedit" Text="Edit" CommandName="EditRow"></asp:Button>                    
               </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle BorderColor="#CCFF66" />
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
          <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btndelete" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="Deleterow"></asp:Button>                    
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Result"> 
          <ItemTemplate>           
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnresult" CommandName="resultrow" Text="Result" Onclick="btnresult_Click"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FF66FF" />
    </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="sp_selectstudentdetail"          
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Tamil" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="English" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Maths" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Science" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Socialscience" />
            </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Tamil" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="English" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Maths" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Science" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Socialscience" />
            </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: How do you bind data to gridview? You can set `AutoPostBackUrl` in `RowDataBound` event of gridview. So you'll not have to get the studentId when you click on the button. It will have it in postbackurl

Comment: where in studententry.aspx or studentresult.aspx? thanks

Comment: In `studententry.aspx`

Comment: Share complete code of gridview (aspx). Add it in to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .ASPX Markup

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Result"> 
      <ItemTemplate>           
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnresult" CommandArgument='<% #Eval("ID")%>' CommandName="resultrow" Text="Result" Onclick="btnresult_Click"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
```

> Code behind

```
protected void btnresult_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn=(Button)(sender);
        Response.Write("<script>");
        Response.Write("window.open('studentresult.aspx?id="+btn.CommandArgument+"','_blank')");
        Response.Write("</script>");
    }
```

Comment: @KaushikMaheta: it works fine.. wheni click button .. i need to display next window page.. for that i used this.form.target=_blank; in page load.. but it works in all the click events..

Comment: @Rani, `this.form.target=_blank;` add to result_click event and try.

Comment: it shows error something is that, form is not defined in studententry.

Comment: @Rani, Please `write` in`w` is uppercase. :)

Comment: @KaushikMaheta: after that in studentresult.aspx page.. I need to add gridview.. but when i add, it shows server error.. can you help me in studentresult.aspx page...? thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95783/discussion-between-kaushik-maheta-and-rani).